How do you use AVCaptionRender in SwiftUI?
How do I preview a AVCaption or AVMutableCaption in a CGContext in SwiftUI?
The AVCaptionRenderer calls render(in: CGContext. In SwiftUI I have been able to get a CGContext from Canvas and context.withCGContext. I am honestly not familiar how AVCaptionRenderer is supposed to be used anyway. The best information I could find is this WWDC video wwdc21-10146, which says

AVCaptionRenderer class, which allows you to take a single caption or a group of captions and render them to a CGContext in order to get a preview of what they'll look like during playback.

Here is the code I have so far. It compiles, but just shows an empty rect.
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Canvas() { context, size in
                let caption = AVMutableCaption("Subtitle String", timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 1000), duration: CMTime(value: 3, timescale: 1000)))
                
                let renderer = AVCaptionRenderer()
                renderer.captions = [caption]
                
                let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
                context.withCGContext { ctx in
                    ctx.setFillColor(NSColor.white.cgColor)
                    ctx.setStrokeColor(NSColor.black.cgColor)
                    ctx.setLineWidth(5)
                    
                    renderer.render(in: ctx, for: .positiveInfinity)
                    ctx.addRect(rect)
                    ctx.drawPath(using: .eoFillStroke)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

